# Embedding Storify posts

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I help manage a site with about 20-30 staff/trusted users and thousands more regular authenticated users. We would like to be able to allow our staff to embed Storify entries in their blog posts without exposing ourselves to undue risk.

We have Media, with add-on modules for YouTube and Vimeo embeds, but there is no Media: Storify module. We tried Media: oEmbed paired with the third-party Embedly service which can provide a Storify post in oEmbed format. However we could not get this to work. Possibly because of [this bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2108973).

We also tried the StoryPal module, but it doesn't seem well maintained and produces a WSOD. We are apparently [not alone with this problem](https://www.drupal.org/node/2509468) either.

Has anyone found a good solution for Storify embeds or maybe know how to get the above solutions to work? Thanks for all advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the lack of activity is an indicator of the obscurity of my problem, but Storify is a very popular tool so I imagine someone else might also have this issue. Here is how I solved it, thanks to a couple of colleagues helping me think creatively about this. Unfortunately my solution only works for one tool, but it could be made to work for any service with a consistent embed code.

1. Make a new field called Storify slug that contains the URL of the storify after `storify.com/`.
2. Add the embed code to the field's template. Below is field--field-storify-slug.tpl.php

   ```
   <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
     <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>>

       <div id="storify-wrapper">
       <div class="storify" id="storify-story">

       <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="no" height="750" src="//storify.com/<?php print render($item); ?>/embed?header=false&amp;border=false" width="100%"></iframe>
       <script src="//storify.com/<?php print render($item); ?>.js?header=false&border=false"></script>
       <noscript>[<a href="//storify.com/<?php print render($item); ?>" target="_blank">View on Storify</a>]</noscript>

       </div>
       </div>

     </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```

I added the `storify-story` ID to deal with some bad behavior where the Storify script was rewriting the DIV it was in and adding `clear: left;` as in inline style.